# Strict mock in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

Is there any equivalent of strict mocks in python? Some mechanism to report unintended call of mocked methods (action.step2() in this example), just like this in GoogleMock framework.

```
class Action:
    def step1(self, arg):
        return False

    def step2(self, arg):
        return False

def algorithm(action):
    action.step1('111')
    action.step2('222')
    return True

class TestAlgorithm(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_algorithm(self):
        actionMock = mock.create_autospec(Action)
        self.assertTrue(algorithm(actionMock))
        actionMock.step1.assert_called_once_with('111')
```

Comment: Which version of Python do you use? It seems your code would work as-is using `unittest.mock` from Python 3.

Comment: Do you mean "any call that were not explicitly set up" by "unintended call"?

Comment: @Cilyan Sorry for imprecision. This examples are tested with python 2.7.6. But I get same behavior with python 3.4.0, where unittest is in standard lib.

Comment: @J0HN Yes exactly. When method is called, but no one predict in test body, that this method will be called. StrictMock (GoogleMock) in that case will make test fail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like it's not supported out of the box. However there are at least two approaches on how to achieve the same result.

### Passing list of allowed members

According to mock documentation

> *spec*: This can be either a **list of strings** or an existing object (a class or instance) that acts as the specification for the mock object. If you pass in an object then a list of strings is formed by calling dir on the object (excluding unsupported magic attributes and methods). **Accessing any attribute not in this list will raise an AttributeError**.

So, in order to fail your test example just replace

```
actionMock = mock.create_autospec(Action)
```

to

```
actionMock = mock.Mock(spec=['step1'])
```

Such an approach have certain drawbacks compared to passing class or instance as `spec` argument, as you have to pass all the allowed methods and than set up expectations on them, effectively registering them twice. Also, if you need to restrict a subset of methods you have to pass list of all methods execept those. This can be achieved as follows:

```
all_members = dir(Action)  # according to docs this is what's happening behind the scenes
all_members.remove('step2')  # remove all unwanted methods 
actionMock = mock.Mock(spec=all_members)
```

### Setting exceptions on restricted methods

Alternative approach would be to excplicitly set failures on methods you don't want to be called:

```
def test_algorithm(self):
    actionMock = mock.create_autospec(Action)
    actionMock.step2.side_effect = AttributeError("Called step2") # <<< like this
    self.assertTrue(algorithm(actionMock))
    actionMock.step1.assert_called_once_with('111')
```

This have some limitations as well: you've got to set errors as well as expectations.

As a final note, one radical solution to the problem would be to patch `mock` to add `strict` parameter to `Mock` constructor and send a pull request. Than either it would be accepted or `mock` maintainers will point out on how to achieve that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible using the `spec=` and `autospec=` arguments. See the [mock documentation on Autospeccing](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/helpers.html#auto-speccing) for more information. In your example it would become:

```
action_mock = mock.Mock(spec=Action)
```

or:

```
action_mock = mock.Mock('Action', autospec=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think that it is not what I'm looking for. As far I understand spec/autospec protect me only on situation when we make some "expectation" on mocked method that is not implemented by real class i.e. when we have simple typo. What I really want is to protect against situation when, code call some mocked method, but no one explicitly predict this in test body.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

### Checking call_count individually on restricted methods

Ensure that `call_count` is zero on methods that should not be called.

```
class TestAlgorithm(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_algorithm(self):
        actionMock = mock.create_autospec(Action)
        self.assertTrue(algorithm(actionMock))
        actionMock.step1.assert_called_once_with('111')
        self.assertEqual(actionMock.step2.call_count, 0) # <<< like this
```

The drawback is that you have to check all unexpected calls one by one.